# How can i prevent app to switch over multi-View in android?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to prevent my app to switch over multi-View, I have already added the `android:resizeableActivity="false"` at in manifest application level but it's not working on some of the android devices like OPPO and MI Phones, etc.

I have read and try many articles, documentation but didn't find the solutions.

Answer (score 1):

A useful hint can be found in the [MultiWindow Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/multi-window-support). Below the bullet point list of the behaviour of MultiWindow in different Android versions, we find the following sentence:

> **Note**: Device manufacturers can override these behaviors.

So I suspect vendors like OPPO and MI to do exactly that. As the answer of @DrHowdyDoo states, this is even part of the Android Developer Options and thus might not be too hard to implement. Also see this [blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/09/12/multi-window-multi-instance-like-it-or-not.html) explaining more in detail what device manufacturers can make your app do:

> In particular, third-party developers can:
>
> - Cause your non-resizeable exported activity to appear in a window, even though you are trying to avoid this by using android:resizeableActivity="false"

So unluckily, this seems to be not totally avoidable as of now.

Comment: Thank you for the nice explanation @BenjyTec

Answer (score 0):

[image: Developer Options Screenshot]

I think this "Force activities to be resizable" might be forcing your activity to be resizable.

Comment: is there any solution to prevent force resizeable?

Comment: @AkshaySensussoft i don't think you can stop that.

Comment: You can't prevent it on api 30+ . However you can prevent it on api 29 or below.

Comment: I have tested it on api 29 and enabling the force resize option didn't work but on api 30 or above it worked and forced the app to be resizable.